# SQL store a registration date as int in a table

Tags: php, sql, date, int

Got stuck with a problem, I have a `.csv`, which I import in SQL table, and need to store the `reg date` of users as `INT (11.12.1990 > 11121990)`.
How I can do that? 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: What's wrong with the _date_ data type?

Comment: Why do you need to store it as int? What's the advantage over a date field?

Comment: ca you please show us a sample of one row in the csv file and also what is the database table structure ?

Comment: No, you do not *need* to store it as an int.  You appear to be misguided.

Comment: Is regdate a date field? Now what are you trying to do with this? Do you have a specific format in csv file and that is creating problem?

Comment: Aside from the fact that this is a completely horrible idea, what have you tried? If you are dead-set on doing this, then it seems to be a simple matter of removing the dots (`.`) from the current string. A quick search should tell you how to do that.

Comment: Got a task to make a script which would create a table and import csv into that table, the structure of the table is: name, email,, bday, reg date and status, and one of the tasks is to store the reg date as int, so I should do it=(, example of the csv row: Gogol Nick, gogol@gggg.ru, 19.03.1809, 19.12.1999 15:41, Off

Comment: Are you sure that you're not being asked to convert to a unix timestamp?

Comment: I'm sure, cuz I have asked the same question=)

Comment: 30 years ago programming hierachical databases we had to store dates as numbers as there was no date datatype. However converting 11.12.1990 to 11121990 is pointless, you can't do anything with it. We always stored dates YYYYMMDD, that way you could at least do simple comparisons and calculate days between.

Comment: Guys, I understand pros of the datatype very clearly, but that's the task I got, so I should do this way.

Comment: Which brings me back to my first question, _what have you tried_?

Comment: Nothing, have no idea how to do this, was googling for good hour or to, on some convertation stuff, but that seemed too complex for thing like this.

Comment: As Emilio says below str_replace will get rid of the . for you, you could also use it to get rid of the space and : in your second date column as that looks to have a time stamp on it. Is this a homework assignment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several way to do that, below the first two that come to my mind.

1- Using a replace (I think this use less memory than the other option to convert to a date object)
  `str_replace(".", "", $date_column);`

2- Converting to a Date object

```
$date= new DateTime($date_column);
$date_int= $date->format('mdY');
```

You have to be aware that when you storage a date in an INT field you are loosing all the optimization the DB has for date type fields.

Comment: Thank you! You helped me so much!